# System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: in 64-bit windows server 2003

Tags: .net

This is my configuration file looks like:

add name="ConnectionStringMP" connectionString="Database=MP;Server=ABC\MP;User ID=MP; password=MP1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

And this is what i'm getting while calling method DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnectionStringMP")

The requested database ConnectionStringMP is not defined in configuration.
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.EnterpriseLibraryFactory.BuildUp[T](IReadWriteLocator locator, ILifetimeContainer lifetimeContainer, String id, IConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.EnterpriseLibraryFactory.BuildUp[T](String id, IConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.NameTypeFactoryBase`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(String name)

The above code is working perfectly fine on 32-bit windows but having trouble only at 64-bit windows!

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the connection string stored in machine.config? If so, machine.config is stored in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG` for 64 bit applications (note the 64 in the path)

Comment: connection string is stored in the windows application app.config, and not in machine.config file.

Answer (score 0):

under win 64 some folders are routed, folders like 'program files' that get mapped to program files(x86) for 32bit apps. maybe your app is located in one of those routed folders ? (windows\system32 is also routed to windows\sysnative, little more on this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigmcmurtry/archive/2004/12/14/301155.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0))